# Why is $\left.(T-\lambda I)\right|_{G(\lambda,T)}$ nilpotent

Tags: definition, proof-explanation

Axler defines a nilpotent operator on p. 248 0f "Linear Algebra Done Right" 3rd ed. as

> > some power of it equals $0$.

Then in his discussion of Generalized Eigenspaces on p. 252 he claims for $V$ a finite dimensional, complex vector space with $T\in \mathcal L(V)$ and $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $T$ where ${G(\lambda,T)}$ is the generalized eigenspace of $\lambda$:

> > $\left.(T-\lambda I)\right|_{G(\lambda,T)}$ is nilpotent.

The first part of my question is why is the operator $T-\lambda I$ restricted? I thought you just need a power of the operator to equal $0$. Also, I would appreciate help seeing, as he state in his proof of the assertion, that it follows from the definitions.

Is it because $\left.(T-\lambda I)\right|_{G(\lambda,T)}v =0$ for any $v\in G(\lambda,T)$ so its eigenvalue equals $0$ which implies it is nilpotent? But that still doesn't answer my first question regarding the definition of a nilpotent operator, $N$ such that $N^m=0$ for $m$ some positive integer power.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for simplicity a triangular matrix
$$
T=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}1 & \color{red}2 & \color{red}3 & * & *\\
\color{red}0 & \color{red}1 & \color{red}4 & * & *\\
\color{red}0 & \color{red}0 & \color{red}1 & * & *\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}5 & \color{blue}6\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}5
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
It has two eigenvalues: $1$ and $5$. Then
$$
T-1\cdot I=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}0 & \color{red}2 & \color{red}3 & * & *\\
\color{red}0 & \color{red}0 & \color{red}4 & * & *\\
\color{red}0 & \color{red}0 & \color{red}0 & * & *\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}4 & \color{blue}6\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \color{blue}0 & \color{blue}4
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This operator is not nilpotent because the nonsingular block
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{blue}4 & \color{blue}6\\
\color{blue}0 & \color{blue}4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
in whatever power is never zero. The generalized subspace $G(1,T)$ is that spanned by the first three coordinates, so the restriction of $T-1\cdot I$ to it is
$$
T_1=\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}0 & \color{red}2 & \color{red}3\\
\color{red}0 & \color{red}0 & \color{red}4\\
\color{red}0 & \color{red}0 & \color{red}0
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This operator is nilpotent.

He claims it by definition. I guess (maybe wrong) that he defines $G(\lambda,T)$ by chains of iterated kernels $\ker(T-\lambda I)^k$, and the result of this construction is that there exists $k_0$ such that
$$
(T-\lambda I)^{k_0}v=0\quad\forall v\in G(\lambda,T).
$$
It is the same ($G$ is invariant subspace) as $\left((T-\lambda I)|_{G(\lambda,T)}\right)^{k_0}=0$.

Comment: Nice. Thanks very much. Would you mind please telling me if my surmise at the beginnibg of my last paragraph is a correct explanation. With regards,

Comment: @TheBirdistheWord Do you mean "Is it because $\left.(T-\lambda I)\right|_{G(\lambda,T)}v =0$ for any $v\in G(\lambda,T)$"? It is not true, since $\left.(T-\lambda I)\right|_{G(\lambda,T)}v =0$ only for *eigenvectors*, while $G(\lambda,T)$ contains much more than that - they are *generalized* eigenvectors. What is true is $\left.(T-\lambda I)\right|_{G(\lambda,T)}^{k_0}v =0$ for some $k_0>0$. This $k_0$ is the size of the largest Jordan block for $\lambda$ (also related to the multiplicity of $\lambda$ in the minimal polynomial for $T$).

Answer (score 1):

1. The operator $(T-\lambda I)$, when considering it as an element of $L(V)$ is generally *not* nilpotent.
2. $G(\lambda,T)$ is a subspace of $V$. You can show that this subspace is invariant under $T$ and also under $(T-\lambda I)$. Therefore you can restrict the operator $(T-\lambda I)$ to the subspace $G(\lambda,T)$ which gives you an operator in $L(G(\lambda,T))$. This restricted operator then is nilpotent.